# dual of $min_x||x-2||$ subject to $||x||_* \leq 1$

Tags: convex-optimization

I want to find dual problem of

$min_x||x-2||$ subject to $||x||_* \leq 1$

Here $x \in R^n$, $2$ denotes vector of $2s$, $||$ is arbitrary norm and $||_*$ is dual norm.

So I started with this:

$L(x,v) = ||x-2|| + v(||x||_*-1||)$

$g(v) = inf_x( ||x-2|| + v(||x||_*-1||))$

I don't know how to minimize this expression with respect to $x$

Reply to LinAlg's comment:

$min||y||$ subject to

$||x||_* \leq 1$, $y = x-2$

$L(y,v,k) = ||y|| + v(||x||_*-1)+k(y-x+2)$

$g(v,k) = inf_y(||y|| + v(||x||_*-1)+k(y-x+2))$

To minimize function above I need to minimize $||y|| + ky$ where $k \succeq 0$, but it seems to be unbounded below.

Comment: add a variable $y$, the constraint $y=x-2$, replace the first norm with a norm over $y$, and then derive the dual

Comment: @LinAlg, I am sorry but I cant see how it will make it easier to solve my problem. I edited the post, maybe I didnt understand you correctly

Comment: I think that $L(x,v) = ||x-2|| + v(||x||_*-1||)$ does not actually make any sense: the $\|$'s don't match up.

Comment: @MarkoffChainz keep $x$ in the dual norm

Comment: @LinAlg, I proceeded a bit further, please have a look at my edit

Comment: @MarkoffChainz what if $|k| \leq 1$?

Comment: @LinAlg, then function is bound below at $0$ and $y_{min}=0$, but can we restrict $k$ only to such values?

Comment: @MarkoffChainz perhaps you should first derive some easier duals, such as for linear optimization. The line of thought around $k$ is similar. Also, $k$ does not seem to be scalar, so you get some norm on $k$ (think about which one).